# python adding extra slashes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create an f-string with quotes.

I have the next code: `query = f"UPDATE \"client_plan_feature\" SET subscription_end = \'{text_until_date}\' WHERE client_id={client_id} AND subscription_start IS NOT NULL"`, where
`until_date` is a string and `client_id` is an integer.

I want to get: `'UPDATE "client_plan_feature" SET subscription_end='2022-05-10' WHERE client_id=1 AND subscription_start IS NOT NULL'`,

but I'm getting the string with extra slashes, like: `'UPDATE "client_plan_feature" SET subscription_end=\'2022-05-10\' WHERE client_id=1 AND subscription_start IS NOT NULL'`, how can I fix it?

Comment: try to print your string....

Comment: What's the problem ? Output of `print(query)` is exactly your desired output.

Comment: Thank you guys, probably this is a problem with my IDE

Comment: Is it an error in the question wording that you want  `'UPDATE `... starting with a single quote?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your slashes - `'{text_until_date}'`. You need to escape `"` because you used it as begin/end indicators, but you do not need to escape `'`.

You can use `"""` indicators too, so you do not need to use escape characters at all (even when you use newlines).

```
f"""UPDATE "client_plan_feature" SET subscription_end = '{text_until_date}' WHERE client_id={client_id} AND subscription_start IS NOT NULL"""
```